# Household data with earnings by each spouse and household spendings

Tags: data-request, research

I am looking for an open dataset on households where earnings by each spouse would be recorded (together with the gender variable) and that would also contain some variables on various household spendings.

Comment: http://asdfree.com/consumer-expenditure-survey-ces.html